# How to find a websocket object in uwsgi to send messages to?

Tags: python, websocket, uwsgi

I am using `flask_uwsgi_websocket` with `uwsgi` for websocket on python3.4.

It works fine on the echo example and it's able to return a message as soon as I send a message over.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_uwsgi_websocket import GeventWebSocket

app = Flask(__name__)
websocket = GeventWebSocket(app)

@websocket.route('/echo')
def echo(ws):
    while True:
        msg = ws.receive()
        ws.send(msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(gevent=100)
```

However, I tried to put `ws` into a dict so that I am able to get to the connection whenever I want outside of the loop from regular API endpoints. Since uwsgi launches many processes normally, I am not able to know what process it's on and even access the connections.

Is there a way we can do it by putting connections in a shared memory? Or how do people usually command websocket clients from a different process?

Comment: If you have multiple processes you should use a message queue, like for example RabbitMQ.

Comment: @KlausD. That part I get. But how about locating the right `ws`, the websocket connection to send messages to?

Comment: What do you want to send through the websocket?

Comment: @KlausD. strings

Comment: Please explain how your last comment should be interpreted in a way that it is helpful to solve your problem!

Comment: @KlausD. You asked `What do you want to send through the websocket?`, and my answer was `strings`. I thought you were asking about data types. Or did you mean something else?